# how do I use rtorrent with a socks5 proxy?

Tags: proxy, socks, rtorrent

How do I get rtorrent to use a socks5 proxy?
I've tried to get socks5 to work with rtorrent, but it doesn't seem to have any impact.

Setup the socks5 proxy on port 9800:

```
ssh -ND 9800 user@otherhost
```

in .rtorrent.rc

```
http_proxy=127.0.0.7:9800
proxy_address=127.0.0.7:9800
```

It cannot download any data from tracker.

```
Tracker: [Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)]
```

And my ip does not appear to use the IP from "otherhost" when I check with http://www.checkmytorrentip.com/

I also tried using tsocks rtorrent

```
server = 127.0.0.1
eserver_type = 5
server_port = 9800
```

This shows my IP as coming from 'otherhost', but after a few seconds rtorrent freezes up.

I am using rTorrent 0.9.2/0.13.2

Answer (score 5):

According to [this ticket](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/850) (and [that one](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/59)),you need to decide what to proxy:  connections to the tracker or all connections (including the ones to peers):

1. Proxying tracker connections can be done using [the patch mentioned here](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/850#comment:15) or using something like Polipo, mentioned [here](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/ticket/850#comment:12)
2. Proxying everything can be done, as you already tried, using socksifiers like `tsocks`, but I suppose there's *no chance of having incoming connections* this way and your BT experience will thus be unsatisfying.

To proxy everything but still have incoming connections, I suspect you'd have to use something VPN-ish.

Comment: So I could setup a vpn from one host to another? Using tsocks frooze rtorrent, and I'm not sure why incoming connections wouldn't work, can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible now with `curl` >= 7.21.7

Solution is [here](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/issues/105#issuecomment-938660465), namely senia-psm's comment:

---

> With curl >= 7.21.7 you can specify CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE as part of CURLOPT_PROXY. See https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html. So now you can use socks5 with rtorrent this way:

> `network.http.proxy_address.set = "socks5h://<host>:<port>"`

> Note that you have to use socks5h to resolve tracker host name through proxy.